# Do active USB extensions cables cause delay(game controller)?

Tags: usb, streaming, latency, controller, extension

How much of an input delay would cause using 2 active 5m USB extension cables with an xbox 360 3m wired controller? Also, any risk of input not going trought?

I'm kinda forced to this kinda of scenario for my living room, as the distance between the laptop used and tv(steam home streaming) and the couch is over 10m, and because I already use a wireless connection and streaming, latency is a problem.

Comment: Laptops can be moved ...

Comment: Not when limited by a HDMI cable to the tv, laptop acts practically as a modem.Plus would you put your laptop in the middle of the room, on the floor? And even then, I'll still need the cables.

Comment: You can buy HDMI extension cables. You can put the laptop on a small (coffee) table. I've done both to play movies on my TV from my laptop.

Comment: The few active USB extension cables that I've looked at all used USB hub chips (but only one of the downstream ports was utilized).  USB specs for hubs mandate at least two (packet) buffers per port, which implies a store-n-forward method.  BTW *"kinda of"* is redundant, i.e. "kind of of".

Answer (score 0):

I cannot say how much latency and am searching for an answer myself, but I can add some experience using USB 2.0 repeaters to the topic. I was using 4 PlayStation eye camera's on separate USB busses doing simultaneous recording for the purposes of motion capture. At the time, they were the best option for hi-resolution hi-frame rate USB cameras for my project. One of the camera's range was extended using a USB 2.0 repeater and was an entire and consistent single frame out of sync with the other 3 camera's, or 16.6ms. I couldn't measure latency with any more accuracy given the refresh rate of the camera's.

A game controller, keyboard or mouse requires significantly less bandwidth, and is more responsive than a camera as in the real world example I used above, and should have significantly less latency to begin with.

I've been unable to find any actual statistics or tests online. For a higher resolution test, you could use a USB->ethernet adapter and ping the router after using a repeater, comparing the results with what I would hope is <1ms without it.

Answer (score 0):

The delay is virtually nothing if all you are using are passive USB extension cables.  Its travelling a little slower than the speed of light, so a few extra feet is beyond insignificant.

However, you did say "active."  If these extension cables are going through a USB hub, that can add a small delay for processing.  Still, the extra time is so small, you wouldnt notice it.